# Почему получается разный ответ?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {

    std::cout << (char)std::cin.get() << " " << (char)std::cin.get();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

При вводе "12" получаю "2 1". 
В то время как при

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::cout << (char)std::cin.get() << " ";
    std::cout << (char)std::cin.get();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

получаю "1 2".

Comment: Дайте вопросу нормальное название, плиз

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Обновите компилятор или включите в его настройках новый стандарт (С++17 или новее).

До С++17 операнды `<<` и `>>` могли вычисляться в произвольном порядке, и ваш компилятор решил вычислять их справа налево.

В С++17 это поправили, и теперь операнды `<<` и `>>` вычисляются строго слева направо.

Подробнее: [What are the evaluation order guarantees introduced by C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38501596/2752075)

Answer (score 7):

Говоря простым языком, порядок в котором будут вычисляться операнды оператора `<<` *не определён*. т.е. неизвестно, какой вызов `std::cin.get()` будет вычислен первым.

В С++17 у компилятора отобрали такую свободу действий, так что при компиляции достаточно новым компилятором с соответствующими флагами будет гарантирован вывод `1 2`.

Общий список правил накладываемых на порядок вычисления в выражениях можно  можно почитать например [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order). Он довольно нудный и витиеватый, так что я бы советовал руководствоваться принципом «если есть сомнения в порядке, в котором будут вычисляться подвыражения, помести их в разные операторы»